# Error when trying to get full list of recent search suggestion from SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider

Tags: android, android-layout

Want to do:
Get a list of recent search suggestions and then show in listview, below is code, PS. already have some suggestion word in database.

```
......
private String string_uri = "content://com.xyz.music_search_provider/" + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY;
private Uri uri=Uri.parse(string_uri);
private String[] projection={SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY};
.....
cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
search_history_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_history_list);
simpleCursorAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,
            new String[] { SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY },new int[]{android.R.id.text1},SearchManager.FLAG_QUERY_REFINEMENT);
search_history_list.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
```

And custom search provider extend SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider

```
public class MusicSearchProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {

public MusicSearchProvider() {
    setupSuggestions("com.xyz.music_search_provider",DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES|DATABASE_MODE_2LINES);
   }
}
```

Issue is, when runtime, error shows

```
cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
```

Changed like below,

```
cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
```

error is same.
But change like,

```
cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,new String[]{query},null);
```

No error showing, but only one result is showing in the listview.
Anyone know why and how to fix this, please help me through.

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution, but be still not much clear, changed like below,

```
cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,new String[]{""},null);
```

Not set selectionArgs as null, but set "" that will show all the results in SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider